# how to make end of buffer visible?

Tags: buffers

It looks pretty usefull to see where the buffer ends. For example, with help of black dashes column, like at this screenshot (look at left grey-colored border). How to implement this solution in my *.emacs* file?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(setq-default indicate-empty-lines t)
```

Or `M-x toggle-indicate-empty-lines` to turn it on and off.

This only works with a GUI because it uses the fringe.

Read more:

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Useless-Whitespace.html

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Fringe-Indicators.html

Answer (score 4):

I've written a package, [char-font-lock](https://github.com/Lindydancer/char-font-lock), that (among else) highlight empty lines at the end of a buffer.

It also highlights the last line (in case it doesn't end with a newline), space at the end of lines, tab characters, and non-ascii characters. You can cherry pick which of the things you would like to highlight.

For example:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Not everyone is happy with it](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhiteSpace), but [whitespace-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhiteSpace) is included with Emacs since version 23.  It does a good job of showing the end of a file and any extra blank lines, along with showing the ends of lines and distinguishing tabs from spaces.  The faces used are of course configurable--I keep the colors bright because I only use the mode occasionally. Here is an example of editing XML with whitespace-mode enabled in conjunction with [linum-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LineNumbers) (which produced the line numbers in the fringe), giving a very vi-ish look to the window:

[image]